# Extending multiple/different objects based on required functionality?

Tags: c#, inheritance

Is there a design pattern that allows me to define an object as extending another object depending on the functionality that I need? For example if I have the following classes:

```
using System;

namespace C_
{
    public class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {       
            Console.WriteLine("------------------------------------------------");
            C c = new C();
            Console.WriteLine("------------------------------------------------");
            D d = new D();
            Console.WriteLine("------------------------------------------------");
        }
    }

    public abstract class A 
    {
        public A() {}            

        public void DoSomething()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Doing something");
        }

        public virtual void CallSomething()
        {
            DoSomething();
        }
    }

    public abstract class B : A
    {
        public B() {}

        public override void CallSomething()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Do something extra");
            DoSomething();
        }
    }

    public class C : A
    {
        public C() 
        {
            CallSomething();
        }
    }

    public class D : B
    {
        public D() 
        {
            CallSomething();
        }
    }
}
```

Essentially class B is an extension of class A. The minimum functionality I want is defined in class A while in some cases I may need more which is defined in class B. Is it possible to have another class extend either A or B depending on what functionality is required at runtime? I could create separate classes each extending A or B but that would lead to a lot of repeated code

EDIT: Added a more concrete example. Classes C and D have the same functionality except that D requires a little more done before it can proceed hence extending B instead of A. Is there a design pattern where I wouldn't need class D and can pick and choose the functionality of C based on what I need?

Comment: Since `A` is `abstract`, you could just make the property `abstract` (instead of `virtual`). Although the question is not quite clear to me.

Comment: you should use composition 

https://scottlilly.com/c-design-patterns-composition-over-inheritance/

Comment: " depending on what functionality is required at runtime" can you explain this some more? Maybe with a concrete example? There are ways to create types at runtime but I suspect this is not actually what you want to do.